# MySQLi get last insert ID and pass it true function

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

In my I am trying to retrieve the last_insert (ID) from a query true calling a function here is where i call my function:

```
$lead = $_leadh->addLead($lead_data, $call_data['number'], $user);
$LeadID = $lead['id'];
```

I am not getting any result? This is my addLead function:

```
function addLead(array  $lead_data, $number, $user) {               

        //check if lead with same number and name exist in db
        if ($checker =  >= 1)
        {
            //return lead id as existed
            $data = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);      
            return array('id'=>$data['lead_id'], 'exists'=>true);           
        }
        else
        {
            //insert new lead into db
            if ($query = $this->QueryDB("INSERT", "INTO leads (lead_name)
                                               VALUES ('".$this->EscapeString($lead_data['lead_name'])))
              {
                  //return lead id as new
                  return array('id'=>$this->insert_id, 'exists'=>false);
              }
              else 
              {
                 //output error if insertion fail       
                  return false;
              }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning array from `addLead` function but while calling you are not getting in any variable:

```
$_leadh->addLead($lead_data, $call_data['number'], $user);
$LeadID = $lead['id'];
```

should be like below:

```
$lead = $_leadh->addLead($lead_data, $call_data['number'], $user);
$LeadID = $lead['id'];
```

Comment: yes i am, sorry i missed out on that part of code ;-)

Comment: provide output of `$lead`